# Error with Loop using Cursors - Invalid Object Name with Set = @

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, cursors

Working on a script to Loop through databases to query one table that each Identical Database has with cursors then return result set to table for each database. I think I have the structure for Set @SQL improperly setup. I keep getting the improper object name error.

Any suggestions on how to get this working properly? I am new to using Cursors

```
   DECLARE DBCURSOR CURSOR
  FOR
  SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name LIKE 'BT_%' and name not like 'BTS_%'

  Create Table #T
  (
  dbName SYSNAME NOT NULL,
  old_Browser_Usage FLOAT NULL,
  Total_Usage FLOAT NULL,
  Percentage FLOAT NULL,

  );

  OPEN DBCURSOR
  DECLARE @DbName varchar(255)
  DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)
  FETCH NEXT FROM DBCURSOR INTO @DbName
  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS != -1)
  BEGIN
  PRINT @dbName
  SET @sql = 'select ''' + @DbName + ''', count(*) as Total_Usage,
  (select Count(Tablestatus) from dbo.Backward where Tablestatus like ''%windows 98%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows NT 5.1%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows NT 5.0%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows 95%''
   or Tablestatus like ''%windows NT 4.0%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows 3.51%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows 98%'') as Old_Browser_Usage, 
   count(useragent) as Total_Usage,
   100 * (select Count(Tablestatus) from dbo.Backward where Tablestatus like ''%windows 98%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows NT 5.1%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows NT 5.0%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows 95%''
   or Tablestatus like ''%windows NT 4.0%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows 3.51%'' or Tablestatus like ''%windows 98%'')/count(Tablestatus) as Percentage 

  from ' + @DbName + '.dbo.Backward'


  EXEC(@sql)
  FETCH NEXT FROM DBCURSOR INTO @DbName;
  END
  CLOSE DBCURSOR
  DEALLOCATE DBCURSOR;

  SELECT *
  FROM #T;

  drop table #T;
```

Comment: Can we see the error please?

Comment: i'm running it here and there's no error. can you provide the error ?

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'dbo.backwards.

Comment: If you comment out the set statement and the exec statement does it print out all of the dbnames with erroring?

Comment: You can also try printing the generated SQL statement instead of trying to execute it to see if it's properly formed

Comment: No, it does not give me any results. Just headers for the temp table. @Aaron

Comment: Thanks for completely [changing the question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/120624/revisions).

Comment: I apologize, sorry. same structure though @MaxVernon

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a cursor to run that code.  You can simply combine the `select` statements using dynamic SQL and execute them all at once.

For instance:

```
DECLARE @Debug BIT;
SET @Debug = 1; --set this to 0 to actually run the SELECTs.
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cmd = '';

SELECT @cmd = @cmd + CASE WHEN @cmd = '' THEN '' ELSE CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) END + 
'SELECT ''' + d.name + '''
    , Total_Usage = COUNT(*)
    , Old_Browser_Usage = (
        select Count(useragent) 
        from ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.sessions 
        WHERE useragent LIKE ''%windows 98%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 5.1%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 5.0%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 95%''
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 4.0%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 3.51%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 98%'')
    , Total_Usage = COUNT(useragent)
    , Percentage = 100 * (
        SELECT COUNT(useragent) 
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.sessions 
        WHERE useragent LIKE ''%windows 98%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 5.1%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 5.0%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 95%''
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 4.0%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 3.51%'' 
            OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 98%''
        ) / count(useragent) 
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.sessions;'

FROM sys.databases d
WHERE name LIKE 'AC_%' 
    AND name NOT LIKE 'ACS_%';

IF @Debug = 1
    PRINT (@cmd)
ELSE 
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
```

Notice I've wrapped the name of the database in the `QUOTENAME(...)` function which, among other things, adds square brackets around the name of the database.  You should use this function whenever appending object names to dynamic SQL where the object name is imperative to the query.  I did *not* wrap `QUOTENAME(...)` around the `'SELECT ''' + d.name + '''` since that part is actually showing the *name* of the database in the results, and as such is not imperative to the execution of the query.

If I was going to use a cursor for this, I'd re-write it to make it easier to understand, and would add some `PRINT` statements for debugging:

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
    dbName SYSNAME NOT NULL,
    old_Browser_Usage FLOAT NULL,
    Total_Usage FLOAT NULL,
    Percentage FLOAT NULL,
);

DECLARE @Debug BIT;
SET @Debug = 1; --set this to 0 to actually run the SELECTs.
DECLARE @DbName varchar(255);
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000);

DECLARE DBCURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT d.name 
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.name LIKE 'BT_%' 
    AND d.name NOT LIKE 'BTS_%';

OPEN DBCURSOR;

FETCH NEXT FROM DBCURSOR INTO @DbName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS != -1)
BEGIN
    PRINT @dbName;
    SET @sql = 
        'SELECT DatabaseName = ''' + @DbName + '''
            , Total_Usage = COUNT(*)
            , Old_Browser_Usage = (
                SELECT COUNT(useragent) 
                FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBname) + '.dbo.sessions 
                WHERE useragent LIKE ''%windows 98%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 5.1%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 5.0%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 95%''
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 4.0%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 3.51%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 98%''
                )
            , Total_Usage = count(useragent)
            , Percentage = 100 * (
                SELECT COUNT(useragent) 
                FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBname) + '.dbo.sessions 
                WHERE useragent LIKE ''%windows 98%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 5.1%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 5.0%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 95%''
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows NT 4.0%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 3.51%'' 
                    OR useragent LIKE ''%windows 98%''
                ) / COUNT(useragent) 
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DbName) + '.dbo.sessions ';

    IF @Debug = 1
        PRINT(@sql)
    ELSE
        EXEC(@sql);

    FETCH NEXT FROM DBCURSOR INTO @DbName;
END

CLOSE DBCURSOR;
DEALLOCATE DBCURSOR;

SELECT *
FROM #T;

DROP TABLE #T;
```

Thanks to [@Aaron](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/66520/aaron) for pointing out the subqueries need a 3-part naming reference to each database.

Comment: It keeps giving me the invalid object name error. Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.sessions'.

Comment: @whereisike are you sure you are using SQL SERVER 2008 R2?

Comment: Yes, I am using R2 @RafaelPiccinelli

Comment: @whereisike - clearly if you are getting that error message, the `dbo.sessions` object does not exist.  Try either one of the queries in my answer, with the `@Debug = 1` - that will show you the generated sql statement.

Comment: I would guess that one of the databases that matches `WHERE d.name LIKE 'BT_%' 
 AND d.name NOT LIKE 'BTS_%';` does not have a `dbo.Sessions` object.

Comment: They all have that table, It runs with no errors now. But it does not return a result set. @MaxVernon

Comment: You are missing @Dbname in the sub queries so they are executing against what ever database you are running the execute command in. Which based on what you have posted would probably be the master database

Comment: Good point, @Aaron